# firebase deploy --only hosting gives Error: HTTP Error: 410, Unknown Error

Tags: node.js, firebase

this is my log  :

```
 [info] === Deploying to 'test-123'...
    [info] 
    [info] i  deploying hosting
    [info] i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
    [debug] [2018-10-25T15:39:54.587Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/test-123/uploads/-LPfsRseOoTTgVVj-keR?fileCount=81&message=  

     Thu Oct 25 2018 21:09:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    [debug] [2018-10-25T15:40:00.337Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 410
    [debug] [2018-10-25T15:40:00.337Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY undefined
    [debug] [2018-10-25T15:40:00.339Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
        at module.exports (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:10:13)
        at Request._callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\api.js:47:25)
        at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    [error] 
    [error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

till yesterday everything was fine

when i deploy functions one by one or all at the same time everything works fine

please suggest something if someone knows about it

it says HTTPS ERROR 410 which i googled and found out that means the resource has moved

so the url requested might not be working but when i put that in browser its working fine

and i upgraded node, all npm modules still no luck

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found this response from the firebase-community Slack group https://firebase-community.slack.com:

> If you are receiving a `410` error, you will likely need to update your cli version (`firebase-tools`). Updating to the latest version should fix it. You will need to upgrade your CLI version to at least 4.1.0 (>= 5.1.1 is recommended).

I was using `firebase-tools`: version 3.18.4 previously, and after upgrading to [the latest version](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) (5.1.1), I was able to deploy successfully:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@5.1.1
```

Comment: i tried npm update and npm install, still getting 410. Tried node 8.9.4 and node 10.1.0

Comment: I had to use sudo: `sudo npm update -g firebase-tools`

Comment: very strange that the response is a `An unexpected error has occurred`, you would expect a better error message

Comment: Also just because you updated Firebase CLI doesn't mean your current session is using it. Best to open a new tab.

Answer (score 12):

For me only installing specific version worked e.g `npm install -g firebase-tools@5.1.1`

Comment: This worked for me, whereas @grailian's answer did not. But I had to use sudo as in `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools@5.1.1`

Answer (score 2):

Update global npm "firebase-tools"

Answer (score 1):

Updating firebase tools with `npm update -g firebase-tools` fixed this for me. I also had to close my terminal session and open a new one to use the new cli version.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was using `nvm` the version of `firebase-tools` was mixed, however this `npx firebase deploy` worked for me.

Credit goes to `heydanhey` here [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/967)

Answer (score 0):

After updating firebase I also needed to run this command.

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the dependencies for the project may help

```
npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Upgrade firebase `npm update -g firebase-tools`
2. Log out `firebase logout`
3. Log back in `firebase login`
4. Deploy `firebase deploy`